# Is there a "moral-index" of fables?

Tags: folk-tales, moral

There is a [motif-index for folk-literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motif-Index%5Fof%5FFolk-Literature) composed by Stith Thompson. I wonder if there is a
similar index regrouping fables by the moral they convey? As a rough example

- **G.** Blinded by greed

  - **G.1.** "The labours of others it is often another who profits''

    - Aesop's [The Lion, the Bear and the Fox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The%5FLion,%5Fthe%5FBear%5Fand%5Fthe%5FFox)
  - **G.2.** "The preservation instinct lost in front of profits''

    - Zhuangzi's [The mantis stalks the cicada, unaware of the magpie behind](https://ctext.org/dictionary.pl?if=en&id=2860)

**EDIT**: I'm indeed looking for a scholarly index, but other relevant sources are welcomed.

Comment: TVTROPES WARNING https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AnAesop is relevant – what you call a "moral" TvTrope calls an "Aesop".

Comment: That's an interesting question. I assume you are looking for a scholarly index rather than that TVTropes has. If that is the case, I recommend making that explicit in your question.